# When integer polynomials take integer values, does their GCD also take integer values?

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials

Suppose you have two polynomials $P$ and $Q$ with integer coefficients. Let their GCD (more specifically, the smallest integer multiple of the GCD in $\mathbb Q$ such that all the coefficients are integral) be $D$.

If, for a particular value $x_0$, we have that $P(x_0)$ and $Q(x_0)$ are both integers, does it follow that $D(x_0)$ is an integer? Does $D(x_0)$ divide $P(x_0)$ and $Q(x_0)$?

Comment: What precisely do you mean by gcd? Are you assuming that $D$ is monic?

Comment: @Felipe, whatever is meant by gcd, I don't think the OP is assuming $D$ is monic.  Consider $P=Q=2x$.  Then you'd better take $D=2x$ as well, otherwise $x_0=1/2$ would be a cheap counterexample.

Comment: However it's defined (monic or not), surely you must have $P/D$ and $Q/D$ polynomials with integer coefficients. What do you take for $2x$ and $2x^2+x$? Either it's a counterexample, or you aren't requiring the quotients to be in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

Comment: GCD should be considered in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ as Zack pointed out. 

Comment: But $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ isn't a PID. 

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I've adjusted the question to clarify what GCD means in this context.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is not PID, but it is a UFD. So, it will be clear if we think GCD as in UFD. 

Comment: See this: http://www.core.org.cn/NR/rdonlyres/Mathematics/18-702Spring2003/131BF378-0B90-4FB0-8CD7-A34115238DED/0/gauss_lemma.pdf 
All things are clearly explained. 

Comment: Then Zach already gave a counterexample...

Comment: Yes, but I am pointing out that the GCD should be considered as UFD element. In particular in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, the GCD of $P$, and $Q$ is, some integer multiple of OP's definition. For example, GCD of $2x^2$ and $8x^2+4x$ is $2x$. 

Comment: Anyway there is a counter example in the comments, but: I agree with i707170 that the defintion in the question is somewhat strange. In particular, with this definition (if "the GCD in Q" is to be the monic, which seems necessary, else this is ill-defined) in the question already Barry Cipra's counter-example works.  
  